# Application Not Installed Android

Tags: android

When I try to install my application on my phone it says "Application not installed"

Here is the code of my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tasklite.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:name=".TaskLiteApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="activity.TaskLiteActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="activity.PrefsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="activity.ToDoActivity" />
    <activity android:name="activity.ProjectActivity" />
    <activity android:name="activity.TaskActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="activity.TabLayoutActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/taskLiteTheme"/>
    <service android:name="service.UpdaterService"></service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: It's fix, the apk needed to be signed, i didn't had to change anything in the manifest file thank you

Comment: Is your 'main' `Activity` class really `tasklite.android.activity.TaskLiteActivity.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that means a few things.

1. Are you installing this from eclipse onto a device? If so, have a look at your `adb logcat` output.
2. Are you installing an exported, signed application from eclipse onto a device through email or a browser download? Then make sure you have `Unknown sources` enabled in Settings > Applications

Comment: I export it, and it's unsigned. I've never installed this app before on my device

Comment: And unknown sources is enabled ;)

Comment: The apk has to be a signed export if you want to install it on a device unless you're installing it with eclipse.

Comment: oh, i thinking it was not needed

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this attributes to `<application >` element in AndroidManifest.

```
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:testOnly="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a release build on your phone, installing a debug version will fail, and vice versa.

Assuming you're going back and forth between debug and release versions, uninstall the one that's there, then install the new one.

Comment: i don't have any version installed on my phone